# unable to make the foreign key get its referenced id value by default

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am new in LARAVEL and i got some issues.

My problem is that when i insert data into the first table i can see that it has an id settled by default but when i insert data into the second table i keep getting this error :

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'etudiant_id' doesn't have
>   a default value

What should i do to give the foreign key the id number of the first table?

Here is my Schemas :

the first table -etudiant- :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('etudiants', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nom');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

the second table -bac2- :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('bac2', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('etudiant_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('etudiant_id')->references('id')->on('etudiants')-
        >onDelete('cascade') ;
        $table->date('anne_bac2');
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

Here is my insertion function :

```
function insert(Request $req){

     $nom = $req->input('name');

     $data= array('nom'=>$nom);

     $anne_bac2 = $req->input('anne_bac2'); 

     $data2= array('anne_bac2'=>$anne_bac2);


     DB::table('etudiants')->insert($data);
     DB::table('bac2')->insert($data2);

return "success";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add foreign key to the data you're trying to insert. So, change these lines:

```
 $data2= array('anne_bac2'=>$anne_bac2);
 DB::table('etudiants')->insert($data);
 DB::table('bac2')->insert($data2);
```

To:

```
 $etudiantId = DB::table('etudiants')->insertGetId($data);
 $data2 = ['anne_bac2' => $anne_bac2, 'etudiant_id' => $etudiantId];
 DB::table('bac2')->insert($data2);
```

Or better refactor whole method:

```
function insert(Request $request)
{
    $etudiantId = DB::table('etudiants')->insertGetId(['nom' => $request->name]);
    DB::table('bac2')->insert(['anne_bac2' => $request->anne_bac2, 'etudiant_id' => $etudiantId]);
    return "success";
}
```